# Is there a single word meaning 'not null'?

Tags: null, terminology

In `if` statements, I am used to seeing `x != null`, and reading it as "x is not null".

But in function names, having to say 'NotNull' or 'IsNotNull' to explain a similar state feels overly complicated.  Not only because it is two or three words, but it also comes with the feeling of being a *double negative* used to express a positive concept.

What is a good word, hopefully not a long or compound word, which means the same as 'not null'?

Some ideas I've already brainstormed and rejected, and why:

- "Initialized" would not be great because in most programming languages you can can initialize a variable to be null.
- "something" might imply "not nothing", and so "not null" to you, but other people's interpretation may differ...

If there is no such word, then you can create one - your suggestions are welcome and I'm sure people will love to vote on their favorites.

Comment: In many languages, the opposite of null is even one word shorter: "if variable then ..." means non-null (ok, often some other values are also considered false. Applies to pointers/objects). For me, this non-word rings like "is" "exists" "in a state of being". Not that that helps if you actually need a word.

Comment: Valid is probably too subjective in interpretation.

Comment: Ruby has a method `nil?`, so to check for not null/nil, you say `if not obj.nil?` or better `unless obj.nil?`.

Comment: I'm really looking for a word not a programmatic expression.

Comment: @TimLovell-Smith good you mention that. For me, "null" is a technical term, so I was looking for a word you could actually use in a programming language. So what is the non-technical word for null? "Absent", "Non-Existing", ...?

Comment: Suggestions : 

`naught`, `void`, `cipher`

Comment: i think we should make something up.  how bout llun?

Comment: naught, void, cipher, and nil? all miss the mark, because (I think) they are meaning NULL. I want to express (NOT NULL).

Comment: Let me propose: Explanationull a.k.a !null - An object which is not null.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a word request rather than a programming question as defined by the [help].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In PHP there is a function named `isset` - I think there's no shorter version than this.

Comment: It's tempting to take some poetic license and interpret 'isset' as a new word meaning what I want it to mean. :)

Answer (score 5):

It is based on your preference I think, isset / is / set / exist / has / ...

But don't you think code readability is more important to understand and write, instead of shortening every word

Comment: I am all for readability. I think if we can find a really good word, and can popularize this concept more widely, it can be even more readable than writing 'NotNull'.

Answer (score 4):

**Extant** means that a thing is in existence.  If you consider null to be a state of non-existence, then "extant" could be considered the opposite.

Answer (score 3):

**VALUED**

The caveat here is **NULL** may be considered a value in some languages, so universal use of **VALUED** as the antithesis of **NULL** is not appropriate.

In PHP however, **VALUED** cleanly opposes **NULL**.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest `is` or `exists`. Many clashes with existing names and syntax though.

For `is` to work, you need to sort-of pronounce it as if it where capitalized and in bold:

if (**IS** x) ...

In practice, I think `exists` will work better.

Comment: I'm slightly tempted by 'Is' but because the transitive usage is so common it feels like an unfinished preposition.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the term `usable`, as in my opinion a reference is usable if it's not null...

But as a non native english speaker I cannot really evaluate the relevance of my suggestion.

Comment: I like this for cases, where a null check is bundled with several validity checks in one function.

Answer (score 1):

I decided on `isKnown`.

`Set` is the opposite of `Undefined`.

`Null` is a `Value`, and therefore it is `Set`, but it is an `Unknown` value.

If a variable is `Known`, then it is `Set` (by implication), and it is `not null` (unknown).

**objects.js**

```
// Is Known
this.isKnown = function(value) {
  return !this.isUndefined(value) && !this.isNull(value);
}

// Is Undefined
this.isUndefined = function(value) {
  return typeof value == 'undefined';
}

// Is Null
this.isNull = function(value) {
  return value === null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use IsSet for the method name.

Answer (score -1):

Being a believer in Both Readability and Abbreviations I use;
 
      "**Not Null**"       where possible
    "**NNull**" or "**NN**"     when I need an Abbreviation
 
It's not pretty, but at least it's unambiguous and suitable whatever your definition of Null itself.
"IsSet" seems a little too close to "Initialized" for a Variant, or "True" for a Boolean

"The Great thing about Standards is that there are So Many of Them" - Anon

Answer (score -1):

in my python scripts for my laziness of writing

```
if value is not None:
```

I usually use a simple function that i called

```
def isReal(value):
    ...
```

when i use this function im usually in a context like this toy example

```
class Bandit:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gun = "magnum .44"

class Me:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gun = None

badGuy = Bandit()
# badGuy say to me: "shot, but if you can't, you die"

if isReal(Me().gun):
   # Defend yourself
else:
   # Im sorry bro
```

Answer (score -1):

How about `plain`?

`is_plain(value)` - check if value is not null
`is_null(value)` - check if value is null

Answer (score -3):

`Straight = Not Null`

`Null = Odd` (1 Null, 3 Nulls)

[image]

Comment: Your answer is hard to understand. Could you please try to explain it a little better?